# как установить определенную версию kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Переустановил систему и поставил kivy, версия которой 1.11, а писал до этого на  1.10.1

Comment: sudo pip install kivy==1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При установке можно указывать нужную версию:

```
pip install kivy==1.10.1
```